# (java) data entry gui builder from (oracle) db schema

Tags: database, user-interface

Does anyone know of a tool that ingests an Oracle database schema and generates a (preferably but not exclusively Java) data entry GUI? Dabo is an example of a tool that allows you to build a GUI  but it uses python and is not yet ready for Oracle (according to the website) and doesn't automatically produce a GUI.

Comment: Are you looking for a web gui or a desktop gui?

Comment: desktop. for web-based I suppose django would be it?

Answer (score 0):

The following tutorial at by NetBeans called [Creating a Simple Database Client in JavaFX Composer](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javafx/database-client.html) could be of interest to you. As long as you can connect to your Oracle database through JDBC as a data source, this should work for you.

For web based, you have a lot of options. Django is indeed one of them. Other is cakePhP and I'm sure there would be a Ruby analog as well.

There are also technologies that go across desktop/web e.g. Adobe Air as well.

Comment: Someone pointed me at http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf-jpa-crud-wizard.html which builds a CRUD web page too.